# Prevent Dynamic CRM Workflow from sending an email to a Disabled User

Tags: email, workflow, dynamics-crm-online

I am using Microsoft Dynamic CRM Online and have a workflow issue.  When the status of a case is modified, there is a workflow that kicks off to send members of the case team an e-mail.  The problem is, it is sending the message to members of the team that have been recently disabled.

**[Example:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hm8i7.png)**  User Jack Bauer is added to Case FOX24.  One month later, Jack's account is marked as disabled.  The following week, the status of the case is updated and a workflow is triggered to send team members an e-mail.

Is there a way inside a workflow to prevent the email from being sent if the user is disabled?

So far, I haven't found anyway to stop the email.

Comment: How is your email configured? Can you post a screenshot, as it is not clear what does "case team" means in this context.

Comment: It uses the "Send Email" under Add Step in a workflow.

The case team set up is complex using multiple entities/workflows.  
1. Case Team Member - Has a user/role.
2. Owner Team - The team assigned to the case.
3. Case - Has several attributes (fields) to store specific team members/roles.

When a team member is added to Case Team Member, they are added to the owner team as well. If they select a specific role, they are also added to the appropriate field on the Case record via a workflow.  I have logic in this workflow to prevent a disabled user from being added to the Case Records.

Comment: Also, the word "Example" is a link to the screen shot.  It wouldn't let me post the image but allowed it to be a link.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by creating a child workflow to remove any disabled users from the case specific attributes before the email is sent. The new process contains the nine checks for disabled users as well as an Update Record action for each check to {clear} the value of the associated attribute. It is marked as "Run on demand" so users can clean the Case record anytime they desire.

The child workflow will be called once per email in the parent workflow because they are sent using different timeout periods. Even if a user is disabled in the week or so between the first and second message, they shouldn't receive the messages.

Answer (score 0):

Add a condition into the workflow which checks the status of the record in the 'To' field of the email.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, there are nine different addresses in the "To" field because it sends the message to up to nine different users per case. Plus, there are three email steps in the workflow. Therefore, I would need to update the each of the three existing steps to have nine separate checks (one per role) & duplicate the email nine times. This would ensure each check corresponds to the right email. That means creating 27 checks with 27 individual emails. I was looking for something more manageable than creating 51 additional actions for the workflow.

Comment: O wow, in that case I would either; a) (assuming the user email address is hardcoded into the workflow To) update the workflow to remove their email address, or b) create a reusable custom workflow activity to cleanse the to field on the email (requires code but makes the workflow config a lot easier to handle).

Comment: While this might be a valuable hint to solve the problem, a good answer also demonstrates the solution.  Please [edit] to provide example code to show what you mean. Alternatively, consider writing this as a comment instead.